# ¿Cómo puedo remover saltos de línea o líneas vacías en un string con PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente `string`:

> El campo Categoría es requerido.
>
> El campo Asunto es requerido.
>
> El campo Descripcion es requerido.

Quisiera que me quedara así

> El campo Categoría es requerido.
>      El campo Asunto es requerido.
>      El campo Descripcion es requerido.

o bien, así:

> El campo Categoría es requerido. El campo Asunto es requerido. El campo Descripcion es requerido.

He intentado de las siguientes maneras:

```
preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $errors)
str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '',  $errors)
```

Pero ninguna me funciona hasta el momento ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

**EDITO:**
Dejo aquí una porción de código y una captura de pantalla de la forma en que he probado y los resultados que he tenido:

```
$orgErrors = validation_errors();
$string = preg_replace("/[\r\n|\n|\r]+/", PHP_EOL, $orgErrors);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($string);
echo "<hr />";
$ltErrores = preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $orgErrors);
var_dump(preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $ltErrores));
echo "<hr />";
var_dump(str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '',  $orgErrors));
echo "<hr />";
var_dump(trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $orgErrors)));
echo "</pre>";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo donde se muestre la variable, para si reproducir el error?

Comment: El primer `string` que muestro arriba está implicito en la variable `$errors`

Comment: Si! Lo se, pero podrias mostrarnos como esta la variable _$errors_, es decir, como esta escrita e.g. `$errors=Texto\n\nOtrotexto`,

Comment: Ahh ya, bueno, es algo así `$errors = validation_errors()` (trabajo con codeigniter)

Comment: @x-rw si, he revisado los links que también compartió aldanux y todo funciona perfecto, no entiendo porque no me funciona a mi :(

Comment: @Naos por cierto que imprime $orgErrors? en un inicio, yo estoy asumiendo que es el texto que dejaste en la pregunta

Comment: @x-rw básicamente me imprime el primer  `var_dump()` que está en la imagen

Comment: @Naos eso te imprime al inicio o al final?, mi duda es que es $orgErrors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La respuesta de [x-rw](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46654/6491) te debería funcionar ([ver ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/77937127e1501cb0bb2fc6f551bd6bb5a4b8c30d)) para tu segunda petición (sin salto de linea).

Te dejo algunos ejemplos que puedes usar para tu primera petición con saltos de linea y la segunda sin saltos de linea:

Con [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) y saltos de linea usando [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php):

```
$string = preg_replace("/[\r\n|\n|\r]+/", PHP_EOL, $string);
```

[Ver resultado petición 1](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68da89c305d39e1ea2d822e63ba4a73a071b4622)

---

Sin saltos de lineas:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[\r\n|\n|\r]+/", " ", $string);
```

[Ver resultado petición 2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2acf3d32f9d4c007457d64af3193271b61ca334)

---

**EDIT**:

Viendo que estás usando el framework [CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/), y buscando como genera los mensajes de error:

[system/libraries/Form_validation.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Form_validation.php):

```
379 public function error_string($prefix = '', $suffix = '')
    {
        // No errors, validation passes!
        if (count($this->_error_array) === 0)
        {
            return '';
        }

        if ($prefix === '')
        {
            $prefix = $this->_error_prefix;
        }

        if ($suffix === '')
        {
            $suffix = $this->_error_suffix;
        }

        // Generate the error string
        $str = '';
        foreach ($this->_error_array as $val)
        {
            if ($val !== '')
            {
                $str .= $prefix.$val.$suffix."\n"; // !! añade salto de linea
            }
        }

        return $str;
408 }
```

Si vemos ahora la variable `$suffix` usa por defecto los tags `<p>`

```
315 public function set_error_delimiters($prefix = '<p>', $suffix = '</p>')
    {
      $this->_error_prefix = $prefix;
      $this->_error_suffix = $suffix;
      return $this;
320 }
```

Entonces según [documentación - changing-the-error-delimiters](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#changing-the-error-delimiters) podrías cambiar el `suffix` de esta forma y así darle la forma/estilo que deseas:

```
validation_errors('<span class="una-clase">', '</span>');
```

Para eliminar también el salto de linea `"\n"` puedes usar simplemente [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace("\n", "", validation_errors('<span class="una-clase">', '</span>'));
```

[Ver ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de62086d0e9a053364c946c187930dea2be2a78b) con el código que usa `CodeIgniter`.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta para que veas los resultados

Comment: @aldanux esta pregunta ya fue resuelta, con las dos respuestas que tiene, el OP dice que funciona, pero a el no le funciona, que confuso esta pregunta

Comment: @Naos - He actualizado la respuesta... por favor indica la próxima ves mas detallado para poder contestarte lo más adecuado posible

Answer (score -1):

te dejo el siguiente codigo:

```
$cadena="El campo Categoría es requerido.

El campo Asunto es requerido.

El campo Descripcion es requerido.";
$cadena = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $cadena));
echo $cadena;
```

el resultado es:

> El campo Categoría es requerido. El campo Asunto es requerido. El
>   campo Descripcion es requerido.

aca te dejo el ejemplo funcional http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/966f9abf712755bfb16254f737fc6de5ea808890

Comment: No me funcionó :(

Comment: Puedes usar la propiedad `white-space: nowrap` de css para lograr lo que deseas, espero te sirva.

Comment: @x-rw simplemente me deja el string tal cual, no cambia en nada

Comment: @x-rw He editado mi pregunta para que veas mis resultados